# How to draw rotated polygons in SDL2

Tags: graphics, rotation, sdl

I'm using SDL2 to draw a couple of polygons on a window for a simulation I'm doing. I'm using SDL2_gfx primitives for drawing polygons, but now I want the polygons to be rotated. What is the easiest way to achieve this? Performance is not terribly important at the moment. I'd just rather not to dirty my hands with trigonometry!

Comment: If you are just bothered about functionality and not how it's done etc, maybe do some searches on `SDL_rotozoom` - I think it is part of SDL2_gfx - documentation here http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/_s_d_l__rotozoom_8h.html

Comment: Also, not the best or easiest tutorial but it's something - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QE1UrKMQMAo

Comment: Seems like it can be done with SDL_rotozoom, but perhaps I'm better off implementing this myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL2_gfx includes this functionality as standard. It is found in 'SDL_rotozoom.h' and documentation of the use of functions from it can be found at the link below:

http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/_s_d_l__rotozoom_8h.html

Comment: The way I see it, I have to draw on a surface, rotate the surface and then blit that surface on my window. Am I right?

Comment: I already did this using a rotation matrix, but I'm accepting it anyway. It might be useful to someone else, or to me later. Thank you.